# Call custom_function for each array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have array with list id

```
[1,2,3,4,5];
```

and to each element I am want apply function **custom_function** and after when complete work all instance **custom_function** i want get result function. How i can do this using library async? My question in code

```
var async = require('async');

async.each([1,2,3,4,5], 'custom_function', function () {
    console.log("finish all custom_function");
});

function custom_function(id, callback) {
    // some works
    callback(null, id);
}
```

How right build this construction?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'custom_function'`. The second argument should be a function, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close, here is an working example:

```js
async.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], custom_function, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

function custom_function(id, callback) {
  console.log("received: " + id);
  callback(null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need for jsfiddle. Also please describe what you changed, for completeness.